# undefined scope error in FullCalendar-rails & Postgres for dbm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, fullcalendar

I'm breaking my head.

I was able to implement fullcalendar-rails using sqlite3.   When I installed it in my app (which uses Postgresql) I started having major problems.

When I try to view my calendar at localhost:3000/events/  I get an 'undefined method' error.

### Event class:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    {:conditions => ["? < starts_at and starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }
  }

  # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
  # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :description => self.description || "",
      :start => start_time.rfc822,
      :end => end_time.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
      #:color => "red"
    }

  end

def self.between(start_time, end_time)
  where('starts_at > :lo and starts_at < :up',
    :lo => Event.format_date(start_time),
    :up => Event.format_date(end_time)
  )
end

end
```

### What I've tried

this is the part of the event_controller that the error references (the "line 5"):

```
@events = Event.scoped
```

If I make it:

```
@events = Event.all
```

then the error message goes away, but no calendar renders.

I cannot get the calendar to render AT ALL in my app on Postgresql and I've tried substituting the "starts_at" text in the scope:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.scoped
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @events }
    end
  end
```

### Full trace:

```
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:5:in `index'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Did you just update your gemfile, or rails?

Comment: Not rails, but I had to reinstall pg.  I can get the json file to render fine, so I don't think there's a database problem.  I've run bundle install and double checked all my gems.

Comment: if it updates sprocket or rails, then in that version 'scoped' is no longer supported.

Comment: are you saying that Rails 4 no longer supports 'scoped'?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll stop trying to scope these events...and start trying to figure out why when I put event.all instead of event.scope a calendar still doesn't render.